# SaxonC 11.1 transform_to_file Produces No Output File

Tags: python, xml, xslt, saxon, saxon-c

Using SaxonC-HE 11.1 in Python3 to transform XML into a new file appears to produce no file. Here's the py code:

```
import os
import saxonc
    
with saxonc.PySaxonProcessor(license=True) as saxonproc:
   xsltproc = saxonproc.new_xslt30_processor()
   saxonproc.set_cwd(os.getcwd())
   out = xsltproc.transform_to_file(source_file="in.xml", stylesheet_file="test.xsl", output_file="out.xml")
   print(out)
   out_contents = saxonproc.parse_xml(xml_file_name="out.xml")
   print(out_contents)
```

The associated XML file contents are:

**in.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<in/>
```

**test.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='2.0'>
<xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes' />

   <xsl:template match='*'>
      <xsl:message>Here!</xsl:message>
      <out/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The [`transform_to_file`](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc11/html/saxonc.html#PyXslt30Processor-transform_to_file) method does… <s>nothing. No output file is created (and I've looked through the entire drive for out.xml!).</s> **Correction:** it does generate the output file in the root drive location (in this case, D:), despite setting the cwd. The `print()` commands return `NONE` in the console.

Note: the `xsl:message` is just used as a check to verify the transformation is happening, and this *does* produce the message in my output console. But there is no statement back from SaxonC that any transformation is happening (as does occur with the workaround I have below).

My current workaround is to use the [`transform_to_string`](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc11/html/saxonc.html#PyXslt30Processor-transform_to_string) method and then just write the results to an XML file, which appears to work without issues. This gives an output statement in the console from SaxonC: "source in transformFiletoString=in.xml stylsheet=test.xsl" along with my message from the XSLT file.

```
import os
import saxonc

with saxonc.PySaxonProcessor(license=True) as saxonproc:
   xsltproc = saxonproc.new_xslt30_processor()
   saxonproc.set_cwd(os.getcwd())
   out = xsltproc.transform_to_string(source_file="in.xml", stylesheet_file="test.xsl")
   with open("out.xml", "w") as f:
     f.write(out)
   print(out)
   out_contents = saxonproc.parse_xml(xml_file_name="out.xml")
   print(out_contents)
```

It's not an impediment to my work, but it sure seems like an unnecessary step when SaxonC *apparently* should have the ability to write directly to a file. There has to be something simple I'm missing but so far, I simply cannot get `transform_to_file` to produce any file or output at all.

Comment: Please try to change the XSLT version to 3.0: `<xsl:stylesheet ... version='3.0'>`

Comment: Also, HE H(ome) E(dition) doesn't require a license. So, please try `PySaxonProcessor(license=False)`

Comment: What does `print(xsltproc.error_message)` after the `transform_to_file` show?

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the fast responses.

@yitzhak-khabinsky : Changing the stylesheet version and the license flag don't seem to have any effect, either. I would expect the XSLT processor to be backwards compatible, anyway, though, right?

@martin-honnen : The ```print(xsltproc.error_message)``` just gives ```NONE```.

Comment: Well, a bit more to this: it was saving the out.xml file to: ```D:/out.xml``` despite this _not_ being the cwd. When I specify a full path in the output_file, it does generate the file there. 
In fact, the Saxonica message boards seem to indicate that ```transform_to_file``` does need the cwd to be set, but that it should use that once done. [https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/4/topics/7658?r=7661#message-7661](https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/4/topics/7658?r=7661#message-7661)

Answer (score 2):

The cwd just needs to be set *before*  the xslt processor. The following generates the output file as expected:

```
import os
import saxonc

with saxonc.PySaxonProcessor(license=True) as saxonproc:
 saxonproc.set_cwd(os.getcwd()) #set the CWD first
 xsltproc = saxonproc.new_xslt30_processor()
 xsltproc.transform_to_file(source_file="in.xml", stylesheet_file="test.xsl", output_file="out.xml")
 out_contents = saxonproc.parse_xml(xml_file_name="out.xml")
 print(out_contents)
```

Comment: I think you can also set the cwd on the xsltproc itself.

Answer (score 0):

*Additional note:* In order to make the transform_to_file() method work, it's also important to always **supply a source file by the source_file keyword**, rather than supplying a PyXdmNode in the xdm_node argument. This is confusing, because the documentation stated wrongly that you could give such an argument, while the function actually doesn't take PyXdmNodes and therefore won't perform any transformation due to lack of input. In some old distributions of SaxonC the documentation might still be wrong.
See the corresponding Saxonica Issue: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5446

(I know that the original question didn't involve this keyword problem. But since I came to this post with the exact same problem as the question owner and setting the cwd alone didn't work for me because I was using the wrong keyword, I hope it's ok that I comment on this pitfall in case others might have the same problem and land here as I did.)

Comment: I think you might have answered [link](mine)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72360664/saxoncs-transform-to-file-produces-no-output-file-when-supplying-xdm-node

Comment: The PyXsltExecutable class gives you much more options. You would create this object as follows: executable = xsltproc.compile(stylesheet_file="test.xsl")